# How to reconnect cloudflare tunnel after ip change

Tags: docker, cloudflare, tunnel, reconnect

I use cloudflare tunnel in a docker image.
The docker compose config looks like

```yaml
tunnel:
    image: cloudflare/cloudflared:2021.11.0
    command: tunnel --config /etc/cloudflared/config.yml --no-autoupdate run
```

and the cloudflared config

```yaml
url: http://host.docker.internal:8000
tunnel: ***
credentials-file: /etc/cloudflared/***.json
```

When I switch hosts wifi network, the host ip changes and the tunnel disconnects.

```
cloudflared tunnel info <NAME>
...
This tunnel has no active connectors.
```

Is there a parameter to periodically reconnect to the `cloudflared` client?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your docker container doesn't recognise any update or ip4 change, cause you running it on a virtual docker switch.

If you try it nativ on your machine with these settings, this should work:

```sh
# run command
$ cloudflared tunnel --no-chunked-encoding run <<your_tunnel_name>>
```

```yaml
# config.yml in your default cloudflared folder (~/.cloudflared/):

tunnel: 0000001
credentials-file: .cloudflared/0000001.json
originRequest: # Root-level configuration
  connectTimeout: 10s
loglevel: debug
transport-loglevel: debug

ingress:
  - hostname: example.com
    service: http://localhost:4300
    originRequest:
      connectTimeout: 10s
      tcpKeepAlive: 12s
  - service: http_status:404
```

here a snippet of the log after recreating a new connection:

```sh
2021-11-18T16:39:27Z DBG rpcconnect: tx (abort = (reason = "rpc: shutdown", type = failed, obsoleteIsCallersFault = false, obsoleteDurability = 0))
2021-11-18T16:39:27Z ERR Unable to establish connection. error="already connected to this server, trying another address" connIndex=2
2021-11-18T16:39:27Z ERR Connection terminated error="already connected to this server, trying another address" connIndex=2
2021-11-18T16:39:27Z DBG rpcconnect: rx (return = (answerId = 1, releaseParamCaps = false, results = (content = <opaque pointer>, capTable = [])))
2021-11-18T16:39:27Z INF Connection 90277bf3-1708-490b-803e-fbdabbbb1f75 registered connIndex=3 location=FRA
2021-11-18T16:39:27Z DBG rpcconnect: tx (finish = (questionId = 1, releaseResultCaps = false))
```

Comment: Seems like the reconnection proccess within docker container take a lot of time (up to 30min.), but it works